# Emmet is not availabe in VS 2022 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I just installed VS 2022 Enterprise in my company laptop. I'm trying to create a website in VS where Emmet is not working.

I checked, and we have to add the following command in the user settings.

"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "html" }

To go to user settings, we have to click file, preferences, and settings. I don't have preferences in my file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Q4i.png)

How I can enable emmet in VS for this problem.